# how to send user id in secure way using get method

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to secure my user id. I have to page **`user.php`** and **`user_account.php`**. I am sending user to `user_account.php` by a anchor tag.

In `user_account.php` page it is showing this plain user_id(as like 25, 26,23). It is potential security threat for my application. I have to do some operation based on the user_id that is sending form `user.php page`.

I get it that first I have to **encrypt** it and then have to **decypt** it.

here is my code:

```
echo '<a href="user_account.php?id='.$single_id.'">'.$user_name.'</a>';
```

I am sending it from my `user.php` page. and user_account.php page just get it by get method.

But how can I send it secure way and prevent user from manipulate it

.Any king of help will be appreciated

Comment: see >>>>> https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_protect_sensitive_data_in_URL's

Comment: Is there a reason you *must* pass the userid in the url instead of, say, in a session variable?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to secure against misuse of the user id would be to Authenticate the user and check whether the authenticated user has permission to access that user.

### Aside

Any other "encryption" method as suggested by other answers is reversible once the hashing algorithm is known. You could add a salt among other things, but I strongly suggest against rolling your own security, especially in this very specific case. You want a method generalized enough be reusable in other areas of your application that you want to be secure, otherwise you end up with spaghetti code.

Also, this almost goes without mentioning, but you should also be using SSL.

Comment: How can we prevent users to know or identify the id passing to the url?

Comment: If you authenticated the user you could match them against the user they're asking for access to. It wouldn't matter if they knew the id of the user at this point, but you could give the user a unique key that isn't the increments primary key to make it difficult to guess a correct user id.

Comment: But that is the back-end process of authenticating. I just want to know that how can I prevent user to show his Id passing in url?

Comment: To be honest, you wouldn't need the id in the url if you authenticated depending on your use case; you would already know who the user is since you they are authenticated after all. It only becomes useful if you want some users to have permission to access other user information (i.e.: admins). Again, you shouldn't roll your own security, there are many authentication frameworks for php to choose from that should integrate with your current application.

Comment: My question is, How can I prevent a user to show a passing query string in url? And you are just telling me about the backend process.

Comment: The point is to passing query string (id, name, etc..) in url without knowing the user.

Comment: As I previously explained, you don't have to. if you authenticate the user, the user should have a session id in their cookies which correlates with the session id stored in the database for that user, which was created after a successful authentication. Therefore the user id never needs to be transmitted. In my previous comment I was also highlighting instances where you may still need the user id in the page, and ways to go about securing access to that user information, which I presume was the intent of this question.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the base64_encode() and base64_decode() methods to encrypt and decrypt your id like below:

user.php

```
echo '<a href="user_account.php?id='.base64_encode($single_id).'">'.$user_name.'</a>'; // encrypt id
```

user_account.php

```
$single_id = base64_decode($_GET['id']); // get id and decrypt it.
```

Comment: This would not be secure in practice. Base64 is an encoding, NOT encryption method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `crypt()` here.

> encrypt your $user_id

```
<?php
// Get the hash of $user_id
$single_id = crypt($user_id);
echo '<a href="user_account.php?id='.$single_id.'">'.$user_name.'</a>';
?>
```

> now decrypt it as below

```
if (hash_equals($single_id, crypt($user_id, $single_id))) {
   echo "User Id matched";
}
```